Getting surface point color in three.js
Could you please help me understand the capabilities of the framework?
I have a 3d model, let's say it's a cube preloaded from .obj (or any other). The cube has different textures applied to each side.
I need to get an RGB color of any given point of surface of this cube, is that possible to do with this framework? (It doesn't matter how camera is pointed to this cube and how the light is applied, just a color of a point using original texture)
I see options such as getting a list of all faces/polygons and and then using just XY to get it, but not sure this will work as expected

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
